# Using R to Merge data sets base on information in 2 different columns--a name column and a number column

Tags: r, merge, multiple-columns

I am trying to merge 2 data tables (csv files) base on information in 2 different columns.
One is a name column and the other is a number column.  These 2 columns in data table A needs to match those in data table B to merge.  However, the number column just need to be approximately match.  Giving example

Data set A

```
    Name  Number   A Value
 1:    A    125    16   
 2:    B    1735   76   
 3:    C    2985   22   
 4:    D    3245   76   
 5:    E    4211   22
```

Data set B

```
    Name  Number   B Value
 1:    A    127    56   
 2:    B    1729   84   
 3:    C    2990   11   
 4:    D    3247   36   
 5:    F    4293   49
```

Merged Table

```
    Name  Number   A Value  B Value
 1:    A    125    16        56
 2:    B    1735   76        84
 3:    C    2985   22        11
 4:    D    3245   76        36
 5:    E    4211   22        N/A
 6:    F    4293   N/A       49
```

I am very new in using R.  Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thank you!!!

Comment: What do you mean by approximately match ? there's any threshold ?

Comment: yes.  there is a threshold (i'd like to be able to set it in code as well).  

In the giving example:
If number in data set B is +-10 of that Number in data set A, then it is acceptable to merge it.
For Name A in data set A, the number is 127, but the Number is 125 for data Set B.  However, since 125 is within the threshold, therefore, merge it.

Would this type of merging be possible using R?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

One strategy would be to paste the two common columns together in each data frame, then join/merge on that, and delete it if you don't want it any longer.  Something like this:

```
# Fake data
A <- data.frame(name = LETTERS[1:5], number = seq(10, 50, 10), Avalue = runif(5, 1, 1000))
B <- data.frame(name = LETTERS[3:7], number = seq(30, 70, 10), Bvalue = runif(5, 1, 1000))

# create id for merging
A$id <- paste(A$name, A$number, sep = "")
B$id <- paste(B$name, B$number, sep = "")

# do it
library("plyr")
AB <- join(A, B, by = "id", type = "full")
```